# How to stop dragend's default behavior in drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, drag-and-drop

I hard to sum this bug in words. So I made the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz_ukKdg1O0&feature=youtu.be) for the bug.
Basically when dragEnd is called the element animates as if going to original place. How to stop the default behavior? I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m91osn5b/) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/igaurav/pen/pPWwXR) for this too.

I have two list for my example, when calling dragEnd after releasing mouse button. The element from one list animates going to list of its original place instead of the place it is going to be.

JS code:

```
'use strict';

var source = null; var heightWidth = null; var lastDragOverElementId = null; var dragImageSource = null;

function listItemDragStartHandler(event) {
    source = event.currentTarget;
    heightWidth = [];
    heightWidth.push(source.offsetHeight);
    heightWidth.push(source.offsetWidth);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    // Drag image logic
    dragImageSource = source.cloneNode(true);
    dragImageSource.style.position = 'absolute';
    // Don't show the element
    dragImageSource.style.top = '0px';
    dragImageSource.style.left = '-' + String(window.innerWidth) + 'px';
    // dragImageSource.style.left = '-100px';
    var toTiltElement = dragImageSource.getElementsByClassName('item-list-element')[0];
    toTiltElement.style.transform = 'rotate(5deg)';
    document.body.append(dragImageSource);
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImageSource, heightWidth[1]/2, heightWidth[0]/2); }

function dragoverHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    source.style.display = 'none';
    var currentElement = event.currentTarget;
    var listContainer = currentElement.parentNode;
    if (lastDragOverElementId != currentElement.getAttribute('id')) {
        lastDragOverElementId = currentElement.getAttribute('id');
        if(document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node') !== null) {
            if(currentElement.getAttribute('id') !== 'grayed-empty-node') {
                document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node').remove();
            }
        }
        var isGrayEmptyNodeThere = document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node');   //
        if(isGrayEmptyNodeThere === null) {
            var emptyNode = document.getElementById('empty-node').cloneNode(true);
            emptyNode.removeAttribute('id');
            emptyNode.setAttribute('id', 'grayed-empty-node');
            emptyNode.setAttribute('class', 'fade-in');
            emptyNode.style.height = String(heightWidth[0]) + 'px';
            emptyNode.style.width = String(heightWidth[1]) + 'px';
            listContainer.insertBefore(emptyNode, currentElement);
        }
    } }

function dragLeaveHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentElement = event.currentTarget;
    var listContainer = currentElement.parentNode;
    var elementList = listContainer.getElementsByClassName('item-template-container');
    var visibleElementList = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<elementList.length; i++) {
        if (elementList[i].style.display !== 'none') {
            visibleElementList.push(elementList[i]);
        }
    }
    // Last element ondragleave handler should be delayed, otherwise it
    // would spin off chain reaction.
    var lastVisibleElement = visibleElementList[visibleElementList.length - 1];
    // Basically last element
    if (currentElement.id === lastVisibleElement.getAttribute('id')) {
        lastVisibleElement.removeAttribute('ondragleave');
        if(document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node') !== null) {
            document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node').remove();
        }
        var isGrayEmptyNodeThere = document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node');
        if(isGrayEmptyNodeThere === null) {
            var listContainer = currentElement.parentNode;
            var emptyNode = document.getElementById('empty-node').cloneNode(true);
            emptyNode.removeAttribute('id');
            emptyNode.setAttribute('id', 'grayed-empty-node');
            emptyNode.setAttribute('class', 'fade-in');
            emptyNode.style.height = String(heightWidth[0]) + 'px';
            emptyNode.style.width = String(heightWidth[1]) + 'px';
            listContainer.insertBefore(emptyNode, null);
        }
        // This delayed the chain reaction
        setTimeout(function() {
            visibleElementList[visibleElementList.length - 1].setAttribute('ondragleave', 'dragLeaveHandler(event);');
        }, 500);
    // When event is on last element set the lastDragOverElementId to null
    // then dragover to lastVisibleElement(second last element) can be handled
    // otherwise dragover to second last element won't show placeholder.
    lastDragOverElementId = null;
    } }

function dragEndHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Check the dropEffect
    dragImageSource.remove();
    var listElement = document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node')
    var listContainer = listElement.parentNode;
    if (event.dataTransfer.dropEffect === 'none') {
        var grayEmptyNode = document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node');
        // When grayEmptyNode is null, that will append at the end.
        listContainer.insertBefore(source, grayEmptyNode);
        source.style.display = '';
        if(document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node') !== null) {
            document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node').remove();
        }
    } else if (event.dataTransfer.dropEffect === 'move') {
        var grayEmptyNode = document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node');
        // When grayEmptyNode is null, that will append at the end.
        listContainer.insertBefore(source, grayEmptyNode);
        source.style.display = '';
        if(document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node') !== null) {
            document.getElementById('grayed-empty-node').remove();
        }
    } }

function delete_item(event) {
    var currentElement = event.currentTarget;
    var grandParentOfDelete = currentElement.parentNode.parentNode;
    grandParentOfDelete.remove(); }

function add_item() {
    var item_text_node = document.getElementsByName('add-item-text')[0]
    var item_text = item_text_node.value;
    if (item_text.length > 0) {
        var item_template = document.getElementById('item-template-container');
        var item_clone = item_template.cloneNode(true);
        item_clone.removeAttribute('id');
        var random_id = (new Date().getTime() +
            parseInt(Math.random(0, 1000) * 1000))
        item_clone.setAttribute('id', random_id);
        var clone_text = item_clone.getElementsByClassName('item-text')[0];
        clone_text.textContent = item_text;
        // reset the value
        item_text_node.value = '';
        var item_list = document.getElementById('item-list');
        item_list.appendChild(item_clone);
    } else {
        alert('No text?? Add some text!');
    } }

function add_item_2() {
    var item_text_node = document.getElementsByName('add-item-text-2')[0]
    var item_text = item_text_node.value;
    if (item_text.length > 0) {
        var item_template = document.getElementById('item-template-container');
        var item_clone = item_template.cloneNode(true);
        item_clone.removeAttribute('id');
        var random_id = (new Date().getTime() +
            parseInt(Math.random(0, 1000) * 1000))
        item_clone.setAttribute('id', random_id);
        var clone_text = item_clone.getElementsByClassName('item-text')[0];
        clone_text.textContent = item_text;
        // reset the value
        item_text_node.value = '';
        var item_list = document.getElementById('item-list-2');
        item_list.appendChild(item_clone);
    } else {
        alert('No text?? Add some text!');
    } }

function onEnterInInput() {
    var e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        add_item()
    } }

function sample_data() {
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        var item_text_node = document.getElementsByName('add-item-text')[0]
        item_text_node.value = i;
        var item_text_node_2 = document.getElementsByName('add-item-text-2')[0]
        item_text_node_2.value = i;
        add_item();
        add_item_2();
    } }

window.onload = function () {
    sample_data(); }
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List task</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list-task.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="list-task.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] +
      ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="list-1">
            <div id="add-item-div">
                <input type="text" name="add-item-text" onkeypress="onEnterInInput(event);">
                <button id="add-item" onclick="add_item(event)">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <div id="item-list">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="list-2">
            <div id="add-item-div-2">
                <input type="text" name="add-item-text-2" onkeypress="onEnterInInput(event);">
                <button id="add-item-2" onclick="add_item_2(event)">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <div id="item-list-2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item-template-container" class="item-template-container" draggable="true" ondragstart="listItemDragStartHandler(event);" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event);" ondragend="dragEndHandler(event);" ondragleave="dragLeaveHandler(event);" ondrop="onDropHandler(event);">
            <div class="item-list-element">
                <div class="item-text"></div>
                <div class="delete-item-div">
                    <button class="delete-item" onclick="delete_item(event);">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="empty-node">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Video describing the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz_ukKdg1O0&feature=youtu.be

**Note**: I observed the behavior on Mac, not sure about Linux and Windows.

Comment: The animation is not working in jsfiddle.

Comment: It's work right in pc with chrome.

Comment: Ok, but as you can in video it happens on Mac's all browsers. Should I make another video?

Comment: That it is strange. I don't know.

Comment: Hi, I see the issue on my Mac on Chrome, but on Safari there is no drag image at all, because you use `document.body.append()`, you should use `document.body.appendChild()` instead, it will work on more browsers. I realize it does not solve your issue, but if you want to be nice with Mac users you can try to support Safari ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your dragend event handler you need to detect if the mouse is over the graybox in the list you want to drop it in.  Note you'll need to write the logic to query the element `grayBoxInOtherList` but this is what you will need to do:

```
if ($(grayBoxInOtherList).parent().find(":hover")) {
    listContainer.insertBefore(source, grayEmptyNode);
}
```

Only do this if you're hovering over the grayBoxInOtherList: `listContainer.insertBefore(source, grayEmptyNode);`

Comment: The UX doesn't need user to hover over an gray box, user can choose to leave it from anywhere in the browser. So this solution isn't what I need.

Comment: From your video I thought you wanted to return to the original location if you were not currently hovering over the gray box on the new list when dragend.  Can you please clarify the desired behavior?